# Using AWS Data pipeline - EMR vs EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I would like to use AWS Data Pipeline to execute an ETL process.
Suppose that my process has a small input file and I am would like to use a custom jar or python script to make data transformations. I dont see any reason to use a cluster EMR to make this simple data step. So, I would like to execute this data step in a EC2 single instance.

Looking at the AWS DataPipeline at  EMRActivity object, i just see the option to run using an EMR cluster. 
Is there way to run a computation step inside a EC2 instance? 
Is it th best solution for this use case? 
Or Is it better to setup a small EMR (with a single node) and execute a hadoop job?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the EMR cluster or Hadoop framework and your execution can easily run on a single instance than you can use the ShellCommandActivity associated with an Ec2Resource (an instance) to perform the work.  Simple example is at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-getting-started.html

Comment: another advantage of using emr clusters is you can use spot instances for long running jobs. which will save you significant amount money.